# invoke post method within get method in RESTweb service

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am developing an RESTful web service for a project. The mobile app should provide an id and the WS need to use this id in a get method to retrieve info from a database. Right now, i pass the id by PathParam as part of the get method uri. Can I catch the id by using a post method and later on invoke this post method to get the id within the get method? Or how should i do it? I don't think passing the id by using PathParam in get method is a safe and good idea

```
@GET
@Path("/MachineDetail/{machineId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MachineDetail returnMachineDetail(@PathParam("machineId") int machineId ) throws Exception {
    System.err.println("test");

    PreparedStatement query = null;
    String myString = "";
    Connection conn = null;

    List<Issue> issueList = new ArrayList<Issue>();
    int i = 0;

    MachineDetail machineDetail = new MachineDetail();
    Machine machine = null;
    Machinedocolink machinedocolink = null;
    Manufacturer manufacturer = null;
    Issue issue = null;
    int manufacturerId = 0;
    int machineid = machineId;

    try {
        conn = db.DBConn().getConnection();
        //conn = db.DBConnLocal();

        // get info from machine table
        query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER04419.MACHINE WHERE MACHINEID = "
                        + machineid);
        ResultSet rsMachine = query.executeQuery();

        while (rsMachine.next()) {
            manufacturerId = rsMachine.getInt("MANUFACTURERID");
            myString = myString + rsMachine.getString("LOCATION") + "!!!!!"
                    + rsMachine.getInt("MACHINEID") + "!!!!!"
                    + rsMachine.getInt("MACHINEID");

            Long maintainenceDate = rsMachine.getDate("MAINTDATE")
                    .getTime();
            Long dateInstalled = rsMachine.getDate("DATEINSTALLED")
                    .getTime();
            machine = new Machine();
            machine.setMachineId(rsMachine.getInt("MACHINEID"));
            machine.setLocation(rsMachine.getString("LOCATION"));
            machine.setMaintainenceDate(maintainenceDate);
            machine.setDateInstalled(dateInstalled);
            machine.setInstaller(rsMachine.getString("INSTALLER"));
            machine.setMachineCode(rsMachine.getString("MACHINECODE"));
            machine.setModel(rsMachine.getString("MODEL"));
            machine.setManufacturerID(rsMachine.getInt("MANUFACTURERID"));
            machine.setName(rsMachine.getString("NAME"));
            machine.setSoftware(rsMachine.getString("SOFTWARE"));

            machineDetail.setMachine(machine);
            myString = machine.toString();

        }

        // select info from manufacturer table
        query = conn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MANUFACTURER WHERE MANUFACTURERID = "
                        + manufacturerId);
        ResultSet rsManufacturer = query.executeQuery();

        while (rsManufacturer.next()) {
            manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
            manufacturer.setManufacturerId(rsManufacturer
                    .getInt("MANUFACTURERID"));
            manufacturer.setManufacturerName(rsManufacturer
                    .getString("MANUFACTURERNAME"));
            machineDetail.setManufacturer(manufacturer);
            myString = myString + manufacturer.toString();

        }

        // get info from machinedocolink table
        query = conn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MACHINEDOCOLINK WHERE MACHINEID = "
                        + machine.getMachineId());
        ResultSet rsMachinedocolink = query.executeQuery();

        while (rsMachinedocolink.next()) {
            machinedocolink = new Machinedocolink();
            machinedocolink.setMachinedocolinkId(rsMachinedocolink
                    .getInt("MACHINEDOCLINKID"));
            machinedocolink.setMachineId(rsMachinedocolink
                    .getInt("MACHINEID"));
            machinedocolink.setURLLink(rsMachinedocolink
                    .getString("URLLINK"));
            machinedocolink.setURLTitle(rsMachinedocolink
                    .getString("URLTITLE"));
            machineDetail.setMachinedocolink(machinedocolink);
            myString = myString + machinedocolink.toString();
        }

        // get info from issue table
        query = conn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ISSUE WHERE MACHINEID = "
                        + machine.getMachineId());
        ResultSet rsIssue = query.executeQuery();

        while (rsIssue.next()) {
            issue = new Issue();
            issue.setIssueId(rsIssue.getInt("ISSUEID"));
            ;
            issue.setMachineId(rsIssue.getInt("MACHINEID"));
            issue.setPriority(rsIssue.getInt("PRIORITY"));
            issue.setUserId(rsIssue.getInt("USERID"));
            issue.setIssueTitle(rsIssue.getString("ISSUETITLE"));
            issue.setIssueStatus(rsIssue.getString("ISSUESTATUS"));

            Long creationDate = rsIssue.getDate("CREATIONDATE").getTime();
            Long executionDate = rsIssue.getDate("EXECUTIONDATE").getTime();
            issue.setCreationDate(creationDate);
            issue.setExecutionDate(executionDate);

            issueList.add(i, issue);
            i++;

        }
        machineDetail.setIssueList(issueList);
        myString = myString + machinedocolink.toString();

        query.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();

    }

    return machineDetail;
    // return myString;
}
```

Comment: show us how your GET and POST method API definitions are now , including the parameter definition

Comment: passing the id by PathParam is not safe. How can i avoid passing id by the   get uri?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood that, you have resource with endpoint like below

GET   http://example.com/rest/resource_name/1

This is perfectly fine if you have protected your REST endpoints(unless if you are developing public accessible APIs) with authentication and authorization.

Your Idea about invoking post method within GET method in RESTweb service doesn't look like RESTful.

Comment: but is there another way to get the input from the endpoints and use it in get method instead of geting the id from using get method?

Answer (score 0):

You can map the  same  method by two different methods annotated via GET and POST

@GET
invokeMethodGET(){
invokeMethod()
}

@POST
invokeMethodPOST(){
invokeMethod()
}

public void invokeMethod(){
}